# import of Data.Path module in Purescript repl failed

Tags: purescript

I tried to import in purescript repl the Data.Path module but got following error

```
Error found:
in module $PSCI
at <internal> line 0, column 0 - line 0, column 0

   Unknown module Data.Path


See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/UnknownName.md
for more information, or to contribute content related to this error.enter code here
```

Which packages should I install to be able to issue following commands:

```
$ pulp repl
> import Data.Path

> root
/

> isDirectory root
true

> ls root
[/bin/,/etc/,/home/]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where have you got those commands from, that you want to run? There's a Data.Path module in this package (https://github.com/joneshf/purescript-path), but it doesn't appear to provide a function named "isDirectory".

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for you response, I'm reading book from Phil Freeman "Purescript by Example". According the chapter 4.16 "A Virtual Filesystem", the Data.Path module defines an API for a virtual filesystem, as follows:  1. There is a type "Path" which represents a path in the filesystem, 2. There is a path "root" which represents the root directory, 3. The "ls" function enumerates the files in a directory, 4. The "filename" function returns the file name for a "Path", 5. The "size" function returns the file size for the Path., 6.The "isDirectory" function tests whether a function is a file...

Comment: Hi Will, I found a solution, I've just imported Data.Array module and issued those commands in a directory where is a self-defined(from chapter 4 exercises github repo from Phil Freeman) Data.Path module. thank you anyway!

Comment: Hi b13v, Please consider making your comment into the Accepted Answer?  I am also learning from PureScript By Example.  Your finding, about the source of the Data.Path code, helped me.